# Unpacking a large text file fast

Tags: python, regex

I have a large text file, which is of this sort:

```
[('hello','how','do'),('you','do','I'),('am','fin','what'), ...]
```

It is built from some 500,000 sentences. I have to unpack this fast enough such that, i get a list having the triplets word in each index,like:

```
lst = [['hello', 'how', 'do'], ['you', 'do', 'I'], ['am', 'fin', 'what'], ..]
```

I tried a simple method of splitting with `),(` however it is extremely slow. Can anyone please advise?

Comment: Could you please show your current code

Comment: With a bit of text manipulation you could try parsing that as JSON with one of the JSON libraries. Is that fast enough?

Comment: Also, are you trying to store this all as one object and then process it or are you iterating over each entry? The latter approach may use less RAM and may therefore incur less CPU activity.

Comment: I read the text file into a variable and then i split the string with '),(' but it takes forever. Plus this needs to happen at real time, so i have no idea how i will manage this

Comment: [`eval`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#eval) is evil :) Should work in this case, since your data looks like Python, but don't do it...

Answer (score 4):

You should do buffering. There is [`re.finditer()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.finditer) function returning iterator object however `split()` makes a list immediately.

```
>>> text = "[('hello','how','do'),('you','do','I'),('am','fin','what')]"
>>> rv = []
>>> for match in re.finditer(r"\(([',\w\d]+)\)", text):
...     rv.append([
...             s[1:-1] for s in match.group(1).split(',')
...     ])
...
>>> rv
[['hello', 'how', 'do'], ['you', 'do', 'I'], ['am', 'fin', 'what']]
```

Actually I don't know how much time taken by your `split(',')`, anyway, above code seems to be not extremely slow for 58,000,011 bytes string in my MacBook Air:

```
>>> timeit.timeit('''\
... [[s[1:-1] for s in match.group(1).split(',')]
...  for match in re.finditer(r"\(([',\w\d]+)\)", text)]
... ''', setup='''\
... text = "('hello','how','do'),('you','do','I'),('am','fin','what'),"
... text *= 1000000
... text = "[%s('hello')]" % text
... import re
... ''', number=1)

10.264044046401978
```

---

Added: I measured `ast.literal_eval()` way with shorter text, but it takes much longer.

```
>>> timeit.timeit('''\
... lst = ast.literal_eval(text.replace('(', '[').replace(')', ']'))
... ''', setup='''\
... text = "('hello','how','do'),('you','do','I'),('am','fin','what'),"
... text *= 200000
... text = "[%s('hello')]" % text
... import ast
... ''', number=1)

12.93752384185791
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this snippet:

Using Memory-mapping a file uses the operating system virtual memory system to access the data on the file system directly, instead of using normal I/O functions. Memory- mapping typically improves I/O performance because it does not involve a separate system call for each access and it does not require copying data between buffers—the memory is accessed directly by both the kernel and the user application.

```
import mmap
import ast
import contextlib
final_list = list()
with open('text', 'r') as f:
    with contextlib.closing(mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0,
                            access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)
              ) as m:
        l = ast.literal_eval(m[:])
        for i in l:
            final_list.append(list(i))
print final_list
```

Please let me know if that helps.